# How to store key in the smart card reader?

Tags: python, mifare, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I am using reader ACR1281 and MIFARE cards.

I communicate with the cards using python smartcard library (pc/sc).

I know the MIFARE key to read the card blocks and want to store the key in reader to use it (as I see in the doc this is the only way to use my key - store it in the reader and 'authenticated' with it the block to read).

But specified in the ACR documentation command `FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF` returns error `63 00`.

In the command above I use key number `0` (volatile) and key value `FF FF FF FF FF FF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly error.
I am using volatile key (`P1 = key_structure = 0`).
And by the ACS documentation for that I can use only one key number - `session key` (`P2 = key_number = 0x20`).

So correct command is

```
FF 82 00 20 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

Wrong command I'd got from another ACS reader documentation.